# How to remove all roles from an user discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a command that would remove all roles from a user and give him one specified role. However, I've run into a problem that it doesn't remove the roles, giving me the `[INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.` error. My code looks like this:

```js
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const ms = require("ms");
let antagonistRoleList = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync("./roleIDs/antagonistRole.json", "utf-8")
);
const commands = require("./commands");

module.exports = {
  name: "antagonise",
  description: "The bot will antagonise the mentioned user",
  execute(message, args) {
    let antagonistRoleList = JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync("./roleIDs/antagonistRole.json", "utf-8")
    );
    let guildID = message.guild.id;
    let antagonistRole = antagonistRoleList[guildID].antagonistRoleList;
    var member = message.mentions.members.first(); // || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    var role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(
      `${antagonistRoleList[guildID].antagonistRoleList}`
    );

    if (!member) {
      var member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
      var antagReason = args.join(" ").slice(18);
    } else {
      var antagReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
    }

    if (!member) {
      return message.reply(
        "please specify the user that should be antagonised"
      );
    }

    if (!role) {
      return message.reply(
        "there is not a role set as the antagonist role, set it by doing &setantagonistrole (that requires manage server permissions)"
      );
    }

    if (!antagReason) {
      antagReason = "no reason given";
    }

    if (member.id === message.author.id) {
      return message.reply("can not allow self-harm");
    }
    if (
      message.member.roles.highest.comparePositionTo(member.roles.highest) <= 0
    ) {
      return message.reply(
        "you can not antagonise a user with the same (or higher) permissions as you"
      );
    }
    if (!message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      return message.reply(
        `you don't have manage roles permissions that are required to execute this command.`
      );
    }

    console.log(`${role}`);
    console.log(`${antagonistRole}`);

    if (member.roles.cache.has(`${antagonistRole}`)) {
      return message.reply("this user is already antagonised!");
    }
    member.roles.remove(member.roles).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    member.roles
      .add(role)
      .then((memberAdded) => {
        message.reply(
          `you have succesfully antagonised <@${member.id}> with the reason **${antagReason}**`
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

      .setColor("#FF0000")
      .setTitle(`You were antagonised in ${message.guild.name}`)
      //.setAuthor(`${userinfoget.user.tag}`, userinfoget.user.displayAvatarURL())
      .addFields({ name: `Antagonised by`, value: `${message.author.tag}` })
      .addFields({ name: `Reason`, value: `${antagReason}` })
      .setTimestamp();

    member.user.send(embed).catch((error) => {
      message.channel.send(
        `Failed to DM <@${member.id}> the info about this action`
      );
      console.log(error);
    });

    console.log(`${antagonistRoleList[guildID].antagonistRoleList}`);
    console.log(`${message.guild.name}`);
    console.log(`${message.author.tag}`);
    console.log(`${antagReason}`);
  },
};
```

What have I done wrong? I'm pretty sure it's a mistake in the `member.roles.remove(member.roles)` line, but what should I change it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`member.roles.remove`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove) methods takes a Role, Array of Roles or Collection of Roles as an argument. You've supplied the method with `member.roles`, which according to the docs, is of type [`GuildMemberRoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles), which isn't an accepted argument type for the `remove` method.

Try changing `member.roles.remove(member.roles)` to `member.roles.remove(member.roles.cache)`, since the [`cache property`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) returns a Collection of Roles.

Comment: Just as a little note, [`member.roles.set([])`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=set) is a much faster method of removing all of someone's roles.

Comment: @Lioness100 Nice suggestion. To expand on that, writing it as `member.roles.set([role])` combines both the removing of all roles and the adding of the antagonise role in one

Comment: Yeah, that's a great idea!

Answer (score -1):

This works for me (discord.js v12):

```
let role = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "RoleName");
if (role) message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.remove(role);
```